# Are there references on solving a system of first order nonlinear odes?

Tags: reference-request, ordinary-differential-equations

I would like to learn about what kinds of systems of first order nonlinear odes may have exact solutions, while trying to solve [my previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/346886/solutions-and-attraction-regions-of-following-odes) (which is a system of nonlinear, separable and autonomous odes). Are there some references? Thanks!

Comment: What do want do you want references on, exactly?  Most textbooks on differential equations have a chapter on systems of ODE's.  Is there something more specific you are looking for?

Comment: @Jim: I checked the books I can access. They only talk about a system of linear odes. In [my case](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/346886/solutions-and-attraction-regions-of-following-odes), the ode is vector-valued, which I think is equivalent to a system of nonlinear, separable and autonomous odes? Are there references on that kind of ode systems? Thanks!